# Best way to create a dateTime object 30 minutes after another one?

Tags: php, datetime

So I have the following code to create a DateTime object based on another and it seems inefficient. I'm sure there's a way to simplify this to one line but I can't seem to find it.

```
    $startTime = new DateTime('20:00');
    $endTime = clone $startTime;
    $endTime->add(new DateInterval('PT30M'));
```

Comment: is `20:00` minutes and seconds ?

Comment: @PedroLobito It's hours and minutes. That part works fine. The above code works. I just figure there's a better way to optimize it.

Comment: i honestly don't' see room for improvement. If you explain your goal with this, it may help us.

Comment: Why do you consider it inefficient, it's only 3 pretty simple lines of code

Comment: @MarkBaker I just figured there should be a method that simply returns the incremented time without changing the original value. If that were the case, it would reduce the amount of method calls by 33%.

Comment: The time processing is reduced by 25% on my PHP 5.6 with 10k iterations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `DateTimeImmutable` to do it very easily:

```
$startTime = new DateTimeImmutable('20:00');
$endTime = $startTime->add(new DateInterval('PT30M'));
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php

> This class behaves the same as DateTime except it never modifies itself but returns a new object instead.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I knew there had to be a better way.

Comment: That's useful to know

Answer (score 2):

With PHP7 you can combine the clone and add methods using

```
$startTime = new DateTime('20:00');
$endTime = (clone $startTime)->add(new DateInterval('PT30M'));
```

but for PHP 5, you're looking at the most efficient approach

Comment: That's disheartening. Thanks that was the answer I was looking for!